# Why does unit testcase run before the init block in companion object?

Tags: kotlin, classloader, companion-object

I have three enum class with init block in companion object. All of them have the same method like `XXX.register()`

```
@Test
fun aTest(){
    val objectMapper = ObjectMapper()
    val readValue: InterfaceA = objectMapper.readValue(jsonString, InterfaceA::class.java)
    MatcherAssert.assertThat(readValue.XXXType,Is.`is`(InterfaceA.EnumA.SomeInstance))
}
    
enum class A: InterfaceA{
companion object {
    init {
        InterfaceA.register(enumA.values())
    }
}

InterfaceA{
  companion object {

    private val subClassRegisterCache :MutableMap<String, InterfaceA> = mutableMapOf()
    fun <T:InterfaceA> register(array: Array<T>){
        array.map { subClassRegisterCache.put(it.getName(),it)
    }

  }
}
```

But when I run a test case in debug mode, it shows running order like

1. enumB.init
2. testcase
3. enumA.init
4. enumC.init

In my mind, the order should be like

1. any enum.init
2. any rest enum.init
3. last enum.init
4. testcase

Any idea?

Comment: Can you show a [mcve] of your code?

Comment: What's the relationship between the enum classes and your test case? Enum class' companion objects don't get initialised for no reason. What does this `register` method that you mentioned do?

Comment: As others said, companions are not initialized until accessed. If you use it to register the type somewhere, then you have no guarantees at all it will be ever registered.

Comment: I post some of my code related part @Sweeper

Comment: in my mind the companion object should be initialized after class load, why do i have to access?

Comment: i did use the companions to register the type @broot

Comment: "why do i have to access?" - there is no really a better answer than: because this is how it was designed. Companions and classes in general are loaded lazily, when needed. If you look for a way to provide a kind of plugin-like functionality, where implementations are detected automatically, then the standard solution in Java is: [ServiceLoader](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ServiceLoader.html). Alternatively, you can register implementations in the initial stage of your application, in the `main()` or its equivalent.

Comment: I would figure out the access part later. but all my classes is accessed somehow in other code in the same way. I think these register method should run in same stage in class load.

Comment: Well you can "think" whatever you like, but at the end of the day, you can't have something run "in the same stage as class load".

Comment: you guys can check out my new post, there is an access of the enumA. That is why  think it should load in the very beginning before the method run. Unless it loads until run on the code line

Comment: I read your code, but there are no references to `A` there, so I suspect it is loaded due to some other code in your project.

Comment: If `InterfaceA.EnumA` is somehow referencing the `A` class, then maybe this is the line that triggers loading of `A`.

Comment: yeah, that is where is triggered. And that is what i am confused. In general, if I create a class by package import, it should load in non-lazy way

Comment: You use a lot of words like: "I think", "in my mind", "it should" :-) Things are as they are, it was always like this in Java. Imports are used only by the compiler, in the bytecode/runtime there are no imports anymore. Classes are loaded when they are first accessed.

Comment: yeah, I use those words cuz the wrong knowledge. I figured it out. Thanks @broot